# Verifying Trig Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm learning about trig and I understand it pretty well except I'm finding verifying identities very challenging.

$$\frac{\tan x}{1-\cos x} = \csc x(1+\sec x)$$

I have spent a few hours trying to simplify the left side but I can't seem to find the solution. I would appreciate a pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Hello! I've edited your post, but in the future, it would be nice to write your equations with MathJax as it is easier to read. You can find some tips here : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\color{blue}{\frac{\tan x}{1-\cos x} }&=\frac{\tan x}{1-\cos x} \times \frac{1+\cos x}{1+\cos x} \\
&=\frac{ \tan x (1+\cos x)}{\underbrace{1-\cos^2 x}_{\sin^2 x}}\\
& =\left(\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} \right) \left(\frac{1+\cos x}{\sin^2 x} \right)\\
& =\underbrace{\left(\frac{\sin x}{\sin^2 x}\right) \left( \frac{1+\cos x}{\cos x} \right)}_{\text{Swapping of denominators}}\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{\sin x}\right)\left( \frac {1+\cos x}{\cos x} \right)\\
&=\color{blue}{\csc x (1+\sec x)}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Could you explain what you did exactly in the 3rd and 4th step?

Comment: @Corpse You can see my edit now, I have inserted one more step.

Comment: The only thing I don't understand now is how (1+cosx/cos×) = 1+ secx. Wouldn't the cosx's cancel and you would be left with 1+1?

Comment: @Corpse No. $$\frac{1+\cos x}{\cos x}=\frac{1}{\cos x}+\frac{\cos x}{\cos x}=\csc x+1$$. Since $$\frac {a+b}{c}=\frac ac+\frac bc$$

Comment: Oh I see now. Thank you.

Comment: And the swapping of the denominators is a legal move? I've never seen that done before.

Comment: This is true because $a \times b = b \times a$ (Apply that to denominators). There is nothing special in that

Answer (score 0):

Multiply out both sides by $\sin x\cos x$

to find $$\sin^2x=(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$(1-\cos x)\csc x=\cdots=\dfrac{\sec x-1}{\tan x}$$

Now $\sec^2x-1=?$

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks!